# Do the Illithid powers have any negative consequences?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Throughout the game, you can improve your hidden [Illithid Powers skilltree](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Illithid+Powers) by consuming more mindflayer worms.  You also get `[Illithid]` skillchecks from time to time.

However when you do either of these things, the narrator says things like

> Something has been taken from you which you can never get back

What are the negative consequences of using and growing this power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the game's been out for a while, it's clear that there was a lot of misinformation about the Illithid Powers going around when the game was new. This is what they actually do:

- Consuming tadpoles or using any [Illithid] dialogue options might get you some comments from your companions but otherwise will not affect anything.
- Convincing your companions to consume tadpoles will affect your approval rating with them.
- A specific story choice at the beginning of Act 3 will give your character permanent cosmetic changes, and your companions will comment on it but nothing else happens:

> consuming or using the Astral-Touched Tadpole -- this will also immediately unlock all of the first "tier" of illithid powers and refund you tadpoles for any you previously used on them, essentially giving you a big power spike, at the cost of black veins running across your body, making you look fairly ugly. The black veins are purely cosmetic, so wear a helmet if you don't like the changes! Convincing your companions to use *this* tadpole will affect your approval with them more severely.

- Using or not using any of the illithid powers or tadpoles will have no affect on any of the endings.

That's it. There are no risks involved in consuming tadpoles or using their powers. All of the other illithid-related "bad ends" are caused by your other choices.

Answer (score 3):

Screenrant, in [a recent article](https://screenrant.com/baldurs-gate-3-illithid-power-consequences-bad-ending/), summarizes it like this:

> - Illithid Powers in Baldur's Gate 3 can have consequences, with certain party members disapproving of their use while others approve.
> - Overusing Illithid Powers, and making two specific choices at certain points in a playthrough, can lead to one of the game's bad endings, so it's important to use them sparingly and be mindful of their effects.
> - While there are risks involved, the benefits of using Illithid Powers outweigh the potential drawbacks in combat situations.

See the article for more details.

In [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15jglb6/does_anyone_know_about_consequences_for_illithid/), someone who finished the game tells us that apart from companions disagreeing with your choices, there are no consequences (and a related change remains a choice).

Remember that you can also distribute the tadpoles among companions, which might arguably reduce the risk of a bad ending.